# VS code - Hide build/echo task for cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, build

I'm using VS Code for running c++ code.

Whenever I Ctrl + Shift + B to build my .cpp file, an 'echo' tab pops up, which makes the entire bottom panel appear and then I am asked to "Terminal will be reused by tasks, **press any key to close it.**"

I don't want the tab or the panel to pop up **at all** and want the entire build process to happen in silence, nothing pops up.

This is my tasks.json file

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc",
        "args":[
            "main.cpp","-lstdc++","-o" ,"main.exe"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Might be off-topic but you don't need `-lstdc++` as it is default, unless you use `-nodefaultlibs` and another c++ standard lib like `-llibc++`  from clang.

Comment: You should be using `g++` to compile C++ code, not `gcc`.

Comment: I need to include -lstdc++ since i start my cpp code with include <bits/stdc++>. I'm not sure about the difference between compiling with gcc and g++ but so far both options work fine for me.

Comment: You don't need `-lstdc++` if you use `g++` (which is more correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured using `"presentation": {...}`. Following worked for me:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Test task",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello world",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "never",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @NguyenKhacKhanhLam You're welcome! You can press the checkmark next to an answer to mark you question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by downgrading VSCode to 1.60: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60